# Swift: Can't catch specific error case with associated data

Tags: swift, exception, jsondecoder

I am setting a custom `JSONDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy` that throws a `DecodingError.dataCorruptedError` if a date isn't formatted correctly:

```
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom { (decoder) -> Date in
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let dateString = try container.decode(String.self)
    let date = /* do magic date manipulation here */

    if let date = date {
        return date
    } else {
        throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container,
                                               debugDescription: "foo")
    }
}
```

However, I can't seem to write a `catch` clause for this specific `DecodingError` type. I've tried

```
} catch DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(let container, let debugDescription) {
```

and

```
} catch DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(_, _) {
```

both of which state that `"Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads."`

Leaving out the associated data altogether, like

```
} catch DecodingError.dataCorruptedError {
```

barfs with `"Expression pattern of type '_' cannot match values of type 'Error'."`

So I tried a different tack, namely

```
} catch let error as DecodingError {
    switch error {
    case .dataCorruptedError(_, _):
```

but this also fails to compile, stating `"Pattern cannot match values of type 'DecodingError'."`

Surely I'm missing something very simple, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in:debugDescription:)` is a static function over `DecodingError`, and this function returns the `.dataCorrupted` case. Thus, you catch statement should look like this:

```swift
} catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) {
```

You should be able to extract some information from the context, if you need more then you might need a dedicated type of error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting `"Pattern cannot match values of type 'DecodingError'."` error (and other) is that `.dataCorruptedError(_, _)` is not an enum case but static function:

`public static func dataCorruptedError(in container: UnkeyedDecodingContainer, debugDescription: String) -> DecodingError`

To handle `DataCorrupted` error in `switch` you need to use available enum case for it, for example like that:

```
catch let error as DecodingError {
    switch error {
    case .dataCorrupted:
        debugPrint("Data corrupted Custom Message")
    default: ()
    }
}
```